# Set different root paths in my rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

How to set different root paths in routes.rb for the same application in rails 3 ? I have 2 types users called admin and normal user.I need to give two different root paths for the users.

Currently i did like :

```
if current_user.admin == true
  root :to => 'dashboards#index'
else
  root :to => 'companies#index'
end
```

But I am getting error like

> undefined method current_user

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is just to route to companies#index then...

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if current_user.admin == true
      redirect_to :controller => 'dashboards', :action => 'index'
    else
      # normal companies index action
    end
  end

end
```

You could also direct root to an action in generic controller like `SessionsController` and have tht controller redirect to the dashboards or companies controller.  That might be cleaner.